# Django reading data from 2 models with foreignkey and make single list

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm new to django. I've been coding with sql but django orm is hard for me to convert my knowledge of sql to orm models.
I've client model

```
class client(models.Model):
     c_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     name= models.TextField()
     age=models.IntegerField()
```

and address model

```
class address(models.Model):
     c_id = models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     addr = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
     city= models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
```

This is my table

```
 ---------------------------
|   c_id|Name        | age |
 ---------------------------
|     1 | John       | 23  |
----------------------------
|     2 | Rose       | 20  |
----------------------------

------------------------------
|   c_id|addr       | city   |
------------------------------
|     1 | buspark   | florida|
------------------------------
|     2 | homesquare| florida|
------------------------------
```

how to get allclient with address in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) docs

> The values() method takes optional positional arguments, *fields,
>   which specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited. If
>   you specify the fields, each dictionary will contain only the field
>   keys/values for the fields you specify. If you don’t specify the
>   fields, each dictionary will contain a key and value for every field
>   in the database table.

`__` allows get related data, so in your case it could look like this

```
address.objects.values('c_id__c_id', 'c_id__name', 'c_id__age', 'addr', 'city')
```

Comment: what if i've another model for account number with foreignkey p_id

Comment: if you have `p_id` foreignkey for `client` model related to `account` model that have `number` field, you can get it with `address.objects.values('c_id__p_id__number')`